# Cucumber report is not getting generated for feature file in karate

Tags: karate

I have used the following java code and pom for generating cucumber reports as per the Karate documents but i am not able to get cucumber reports as expected:

In Java Class file :

```
package Mav_demo.RunnerFunction;

//import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateStats;
//import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
//import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
//@RunWith(Karate.class)
//@CucumberOptions(features = 
"classpath:src/test/java/Mav_demo/RunnerFunction/gapi_mulscn.feature")
@CucumberOptions(tags = "~@ignore") 
public class Looping{

@Test
public void testParallel() {
    String karateOutputPath = "target/surefire-reports";
    KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 5, karateOutputPath);
    generateReport(karateOutputPath);
    assertTrue("there are scenario failures", stats.getFailCount() == 0);        
}

private static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
    Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
    List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<String>(jsonFiles.size());
    jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "demo");
    ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
    reportBuilder.generateReports();        
}
}
```

In Pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>Mav_Demo.RunnerFunction</groupId>
<artifactId>RunnerFunction</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version>
    <selenium.version>2.53.0</selenium.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.3</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>    

<dependencies> 
    <dependency>
<groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
<artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
<version>0.7.0</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
<version>3.8.0</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>               
</dependencies>

<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>Mav_demo.RunnerFunction/ExamplesTest.java</include>
        </includes>
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
    <systemProperties>
        <cucumber.options>--tags ~@ignore</cucumber.options>
    </systemProperties>            
    </configuration>
</plugin>            
    </plugins>        
</build>
```

In Feature file :

```
Feature: to print results
Scenario: looping the post method

Given url 'https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate'
And param key = 'AIzaSyB2jt4BQ9McqBXAe8dYcp1CwKf0oGFlWuc'
And request 'payload'
When method post
And print response
Then status 200
```

I am getting sure-fire reports correctly. But, not the Cucumber report. Kindly please help on this.

Thanks much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry no-one is going to read all this and figure out since this seems to be a horrible mix of Cucumber, Selenium and what not.

Please refer to this document: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Anyway, here is what I suggest. Create a fresh project using the Maven quickstart (or archetype): https://github.com/intuit/karate#quickstart

Then get the parallel reports working in that project. Refer to https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report - and note that you seem to be using a different version of the cucumber-reporting artifact.

Once you have that working and understand clearly what to do - then try to put all this into your existing (old) project. All the best.

Comment: Thanks much for your reply @peterThomas. I am sucessfully getting the Cucumber reports too.